# Angular show a text on hover depending on the state displayed in a <td>

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working in an Angular 7 project where have a `<td>` that I display diffrent colors to show the user the status of their task.
Red - Shows work is 'Delayed'
Orange - 'In progress'
Grey - 'Rejected'

At the moment I have manged to display these status colors, however now I want to add a text display on hover - when the user hover on each status they should be shown a message explaining meaning of the color.

I have the following code
Html:

```
<td data-label="Status" class="cell status-cell">
   <span [style.backgroundColor]="getStatus(working_period)"></span>
     <p>Text on hover here</p>
</td>
```

Typescript:

```
public getStatus(period: WorkingPeriod): string {
    if (+period.status !== 2) {
      return 'grey';
    }
    const time: number = +new Date() - +period.endDate;
    if (time > 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
      return `red`;
    }
    return 'orange';
  }
```

I have **NO** problem with text hovering.

My problem is is in matching the Text with the color displayed.

See my `<td>`
In this case for example, the text below orange I want it to be 'In progress', below red 'Delayed'.
[image]

*(Please don't bash me I am still learning Angular)*

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a member to your component class and set its value according to the status.

```html
<td data-label="Status" class="cell status-cell">
   <span [style.backgroundColor]="getStatus(working_period)"></span>
     <p>{{hoverText}}</p>
</td>
```

```js
hoverText: string;

public getStatus(period: WorkingPeriod): string {
  const time: number = +new Date() - +period.endDate;
  if (+period.status !== 2) {
    this.hoverText = "Rejected";
    return 'grey';
  } else if (time > 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
    this.hoverText = "Delayed";
    return `red`;
  } else {
    this.hoverText = "In progress";
  }
  return 'orange';
}
```